# Scala/ AKKA actor migration between machines

Tags: scala, migration, akka, actor

Can running actors be migrated to a different node during their life cycle? According to this AKKA road map [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18W9-fKs55wiFNjXL9q50PYOnR7-nnsImzJqHOPPbM4E/mobilebasic?pli=1&hl=en_US) automatic actor migration upon failure would be available with release "Rollins". I was wondering whether this actor migration can somehow be done manually, via some special message or anything? Furthermore, is there anything similar to this in Scala?

Comment: The plans for Rollins will be revised soon. Whether actor migration will be part of it or not, and in what shape, might change.

Comment: Would be great if this made it into akka 2.3!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case, akka-cluster with [cluster sharding](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/contrib/cluster-sharding.html#cluster-sharding) may be a fit.
Module is capable of reallocating shards to other cluster nodes.